# Bold and Colored Image Caption

Tags: formatting, color, captions

How can I color and bold an image's caption in `\documentclass[12pt]{report}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `documentclass`, as, I believe, in any `documentclass`, it is possible to use the `caption` package and the `\textcolor` command.

For example, if I want to color blue and bold the caption of a simple triangle drawn in TikZ in your `documentclass`, I can use the following code to achieve the following output, which I will break down below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=blue,bf}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0) -- (3,2) -- (4,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{A triangle.}}}
    \label{fig:triangle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I began by declaring your `documentclass` of choice. Next, I called in `tikz` for the triangle and `caption` to change the color of "Figure 1:". I modified `caption` with two constraints under one modifier (labelfont), namely declaring the color to be blue (although it could be many others) and "bf" for boldface.

Then, down in the actual figure, I used `\textbf{\textcolor{<color>}{<caption>}}`. This combines the two separate commands to color the caption, itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem, is that any cross-reference to this figure will also be in blue and boldface…

Comment: @Bernard, not really, only cross reference will be only bold and not colored.

Comment: @Zarko: really? In any case, it is preferable to do that through the `caption` package.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly improved version of @Shady Puck answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={color=blue,bf}} % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A triangle.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
See figure~\ref{fig:myfig}   % <---

\end{document}
```

[image]